# Traversing a tree in prolog

Tags: prolog

Can someone help me with a problem in Prolog. I want to traverse a tree InOrder . I managed to do it in postOrder because it seemed siplier, but I dont't know how to change it inOrder. I only assume that my code works because I don't know how to declare a tree in the Goal section. Can anyone help me please. Here is my code so far:

```
domains
  elem=integer
  tree=tr(elem,tree,tree);nil
  list=elem*
predicates
  preorder(tree,list)
  conc(list,list,list)
clauses
  conc([],L,L).
  conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-
                          conc(L1,L2,L3). 
  preorder(nil,[]).
  preorder(tr(R,LEFT,RIGHT),L):-
    preorder(RIGHT,L1),
    preorder(LEFT,L2),
    conc([R],L2,L3),
    conc(L3,L1,L)
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `domains` section, seems that you need to change

```
preorder(arb(R,LEFT,RIGHT),L):-
  ...
```

to

```
preorder(tr(R,LEFT,RIGHT),L):-
    ...
```

*edit* basically, visit order isn't influent, since you're not 'doing' anything with tree' data... you could just change the conc to get an inorder list. For discussion'sake, let's rename the predicate (remember to declare it in `predicates` section):

```
inorder(nil,[]).
inorder(tr(R,LEFT,RIGHT),L):-
    inorder(LEFT,L1),
    conc(L1,[R],X),
    inorder(RIGHT,L2),
    conc(X,L2,L).
```

yields

```
11 ?- inorder(tr(1,tr(2,tr(4,nil,nil),nil),tr(3,nil,nil)),L).
L = [4, 2, 1, 3].
```

Comment: That is only a syntax error, I've change the names in english because they were in another language, so that it can be understood. I don't know how to do it, and what should I put in the GOAL section?

Comment: I don't have winprolog available to test, but think should be `goal preorder(tr(1,nil,nil),L).`

Comment: It shows [1]. If I want to write a bigger tree like this one 1->[2,3->[5->[8,9],6->[10]],4->[10]] how do I do it?

Comment: Ok just help me with a simple example for 1->[1,2] please

Comment: `preorder(tr(1,tr(2,nil,nil),tr(3,nil,nil)))`

Comment: I tried to add another node but no success My code        preorder(tr(1,tr(2,tr(4,nil,nil),nil,nil),tr(3,nil,nil)))

Comment: you have too much nils here `tr(2,tr(4,nil,nil),nil,nil)`, should be `tr(2,tr(4,nil,nil),nil)`

Comment: I fixed it. Could you help traverse this tree InOrder?

Comment: conc/3 is exactly append/3. I think it's easy to find out on SO how append/3 works. Anyway, it's a `relation` among 3 lists. It goes down to the empty list (first arg), attaching arguments to the second one.